# Python Error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 76: invalid start byte

Tags: python

I´m new in Python and I looked a tutorial. I coded it like there, but it always shows:

```
command_output = subprocess.run(["netsh", "wlan", "show", "profiles"], capture_output = True).stdout.decode()
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 76: invalid start byte
```

Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Have you tried running the command in a shell and seeing what's at position 76 in the output?

Answer (score 1):

This probably means the output stored in `stdout` is not UTF-encoded. You can try passing another character encoding as an argument to decode. Latin-1 can handle 0x81, though it has no character to display.

```py
>>> b'\x81'.decode('latin-1')
'\x81'
```

[0x81 character description.](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+0081)